# RabbitMQ with Python: Acknowledging and rejecting messages individually while using executemany()

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mysql-python

I plan on receiving over 5 million messages a day with rabbitmq and I only have control over the consumer side. I wanted to use executemany to store the messages in batches but sometimes a message may be caught in an exception and I want just those individual messages to be rejected and simply acknowledge the rest. How can I selectively reject and acknowledge after an executemany()?

```
insert_sql = '''MERGE INTO table1
                        USING (
                        SELECT :col1 COL1, TO_TIMESTAMP(:col2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9') COL2, 
                        :col3 COL3, :col4 COL4
                        FROM DUAL
                        ) source_table
                        ON (table1.COL1 = source_table.COL1 AND table1.COL2 = source_table.COL2 
                        AND table1.COL3 = source_table.COL3 AND table1.COL4 = source_table.COL4) 
                        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                        INSERT (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL8)
                        VALUES (:col1, TO_TIMESTAMP(:col2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9'), :col3, 
                        :col4, :col5, xmltype(:col6), xmltype(:col7))'''

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    # some code to clean up the body, snipping it off
    # ...
    if decompressed_j == None:
        _reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=False)
    elif isinstance(decompressed_j, dict):
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        global acx_list
        acx = ACX_Obj(decompressed_j, raw_jsonArray)
        if acx.response.startswith('<someignorabletag>'):
            ch.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=False)
        else:
            acx_list.append(acx.transactionValues)
        if len(acx_list) % 20 == 0:
            try:
                ora_exe(acx_list, ch, method)
            except AttributeError as att_e:
                print(att_e)
                ch.basic_reject(
                    delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=False)
                raise att_e
            acx_list = []
    else:
        ch.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=False)

def ora_exe(acx_list, ch, method):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('dummy1/dummyenv', threaded=True)
    c = conn.cursor()
    try:
        c.executemany(insert_sql, acx_list)
    except cx_Oracle.IntegrityError as integrity_err:
        print('integrity err')
        conn.rollback()
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as db_err:
        print(db_err)
        conn.rollback()
    else:
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        c.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Could you break your transactions into manageable sizes, then if you hit an exception, run through each message in the single transaction? 5m messages shouldn't be *too* horrible for that kind of paradigm, though it kind of negates the benefit of transacted sessions anyways

Comment: Though `manageable` here is completely subjective

Comment: It could hold as a temporary solution but remember that each message is being appended into a list before it is passed into executemany() which means that if executemany() hits an exception and I start looping through each item in the list to do execute()'s, I cannot mark the older messages which were appended first as rejected.